# Discord bot suddenly dropping connections

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have been working on a bot for the past weeks and everything seemed to be going well. When most of the basic the code was ready I decided to put it online while continue updating it. 
Running it on my laptop did not raise any trouble of this kind, however when I installed it in my VPS and ran it from there it seemed to be having issues:

NPM version is *6.9.0* while node.js version is *12.1.0.*
Discord.js version is *0.8.2*

I read some previous threads of people having this issue, however beside catching *uncaughtException* I couldn't find any way to actually fix it.

This is the error I can catch in my terminal with the "error" event listener of Discord Client object:

```
(node:5720) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: 
Error: read ECONNRESET at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:183:27)

(node:5720) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.
This error originated either by throwing inside of an 
async function without a catch block, 
or by rejecting a promise which was 
not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
```

This is the result of a tracert to *gateway.discord.gg*:

```
Tracing route to 162.159.135.234 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  62.113.192.77
  3     2 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  62.113.192.113
  4     8 ms    14 ms    12 ms  de-cix-frankfurt.as13335.net [80.81.194.180]
  5    <1 ms     1 ms    <1 ms  162.159.135.234

Trace complete.
```

Can this timed out request be the issue? Because when I Tracert from my pc it never occurs.

Comment: Discord.js version 0.8.2? You might want to update your package mate, that is really old.

Comment: v12-dev, is the newest, how foes one have 0.8.2?

Comment: updated to

    `+ discord.js@11.5.1`

    `updated 2 packages and audited 7 packages in 11.564s`

    `found 0 vulnerabilities`